# Runtime crash when pushing onto a queue a struct containing a pointer to that type of queue

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, queue, pass-by-reference

I am trying to create a tree in which each node (struct) has a string field for its name and a queue< Node >* field for a queue containing its child nodes.

The sample code below is a small program which isolates the error I am receiving in my larger, complex program. It eliminates anything unrelated to my error, but resembles the original code that is problematic. I receive the same error at the same place as in my complete code, which is a runtime crash. The compiler gives me no warnings when compiling.

The crash occurs when I attempt to push a node onto one of the queues, which has been passed by reference into a function after being deferenced from a pointer.

The comments containing numbers in my code show the order of execution it follows.

```
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using std::string;
using std::queue;

// the tree node structure
typedef struct Node
{
    string name; // the name of this node
    queue<Node>* children; // a queue containing the child nodes
} Node;

Node makeNode(string name)
{
    queue<Node> children = {}; // 2, 7, 12
    Node n = {name, &children}; // 3, 8, 13
    return n; // 4, 9, 14
}

void funcTwo(queue<Node>& nodes)
{
    Node n = makeNode("Child of Child of Root"); // 11
    cout << "Program prints this." << endl; // 15
    nodes.push(n); // PROGRAM CRASHES HERE
    cout << "Program does not print this." << endl;
}


void funcOne(queue<Node>& nodes)
{
    Node n = makeNode("Child of Root"); // 6
    funcTwo(*n.children); // 10
    nodes.push(n);
}

int main()
{
    Node root = makeNode("Root"); // 1
    funcOne(*root.children); // 5
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

> Compiler: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86
>
> OS: Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `makeNode` function you pass a stack variable to the children member. When this stack frame is popped, the memory is deallocated and you are left with a dangling pointer. You should allocate on the heap using either `new` or `std::make_shared`, so that the memory is not deallocated when the stack frame is popped.